# Can i tell python to do something with a button at a location in a grid that I give it?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, configure

So I'm wondering if and how I would tell python something like: here's the row and column in which a button is located, now do something to it. This is what I have now.

```
(Can I input the row and column or something here).config(...)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this is *not a discussion forum*, and that you are expected to ask *one question at a time* here. Read [ask] for details. I'm confused about your first question. What do you mean by "the row and column in which a button is located"? Why is the button necessarily in a row and column at all? Regarding the second, did you try reading the documentation for `.configure`? What did it tell you, and why was that not enough to solve the problem?

Comment: I am making a grid based gui so each button is in a certain row and column and I have those values saved so I'm trying to use those "coordinates" in the grid to, without knowing which button is in that certain position in the grid, tell python to do something with that button. Essentially I want to know if python can figure out what is on certain coordinates of a grid.

Comment: Did you consider just using data in your program to *remember* where the button is?

Comment: I did not because I wanted to see if there was a different way of doing it, maybe a bulit in function. I am still very new to tkinter so I was curious. I will try it this way, thank you.

Comment: Try `container.grid_slaves(row=row, column=column)[0].config(...)` if `container` is the parent of the button at grid (row, column).

Answer (score 2):

As @Karl mentioned, it would be easiest to just *remember* where your widgets are, say with a 2d list. However, you can find where a widget has been placed using the `grid` method using `parent.winfo_children()` and `widget.grid_info()`. An example of this is:

```
def find_widget(parent, row, column):
    widgets = parent.winfo_children()
    for widget in widgets:
        widget_grid = widget.grid_info()
        if widget_grid["column"] == column and widget_grid["row"] == row:
            # You have found the widget in your coordinates
            return widget
    else:
        # No widget matches your coordinates
        return None
```

This will only work if all the widgets in your grid have the same parent, so using a frame would likely be ideal. You can then configure your returned widget however you need